# when I shoud use format() function and str() function. which one is better?

Tags: python-3.x

I am stuck to find out better one between str() and format() in python

```
  "SELECT schools.deis_income , schools.school_name,SUM(money.coin_in_amount) AS coinamount, SUM(money.note_in_amount) AS noteamount , SUM(money.coffee_coin_in_amount) AS coffeeamount , SUM(money.coin_out_amount) AS coinoutamount, SUM(money.note_out_amount) AS noteoutamount FROM money_transactions AS money JOIN school_admin_details AS sa on sa.id = money.school_admin_id JOIN schools ON schools.id=sa.school_id WHERE sa.school_id ={school_id} AND money.transaction_time BETWEEN '{start_date}' AND '{end_date}' GROUP BY schools.id".format(school_id=school_id,start_date=start_date,end_date=end_date)
```

I use format function here.  can I use str() ? 
please tell me which one give me quick result, str() or format() ???

Comment: It's already a string. Why would you use str?!

Comment: thanks, pls tell me which one is better and why?

Comment: They do completely different things. I say format is better because it sounds more like wombat.

Comment: pls tell me the reason

Comment: .format() formats a string (like above). str() turns things into strings. Which is better depends on what you need to do, you can't compare them like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your question is which of this:

```
foo = "some text " + str(some_var) + " and some other text"
```

or this:

```
foo = "some text {} and some other text".format(var)
```

is "better", the general consensus is very clear: string formatting is much easier to read and maintain and the one pythonic way to go.

Now for your particular example, the answer is that both are totally wrong - [unless you're ok to give full access to your database](https://bobby-tables.com/) to even the most inept script kiddie. [For SQL queries, the proper solution is to use prepared statements](https://bobby-tables.com/python), where your db connector will take care of proper formatting **and sanitizing** of the values:

```
# assumes MySQL - for other vendors check your own
# db-api connector's doc for the correct placeholder


query =  "SELECT somefield FROM mytable where somedate > %(somedate)s and something_else = %(someval)s"

cursor.execute(query, {"somedate": some_date, "someval": 42})
```

Comment: Pls tell me the execution time also in both str and format function

Comment: Seriously, there's not much difference and you shouldn't worry - `.format()` is the officially blessed, canonical, pythonic solution, and it's (mostly) builtin so quite optimized already, so just  use it.